# Creating soql query using getDescribe

Tags: soql

I currently have a function that creates a soql query with all queryable fields on a sobject

```
Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> fields = newObj.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();

for (String s : fields.keySet()) {

    Schema.Describefieldresult dfr = fields.get(s).getDescribe();
    if (dfr.isAccessible()) {
        accessibleFields.add(s);
    }
}

String query = 'SELECT '
             + String.join(new List<String>(accessibleFields), ', ')
             + ' FROM ' + objectName;
```

Just recently I've been getting this error when querying Account

```
System.QueryException: No such column 'billinglongitude' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

a quick google search shows that this field is a pilot standard field.

Is there a workaround for this that doesn't involve hardcoding which fields to ignore?

**Update**:
The resolution from the salesforce case is to update the API version to the latest one.
I was using v27 and at the time of this post, the latest is v29

This also means I will periodically update the api version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of bug has raised itself before with Apex Describe and pilot features, I've not been able to find a workaround then either. You could argue that in some way all schema features are technically enabled through an Apex Describe, but then i would expect something like isAccessible to help us detect those that have not been switched on, as you have attempted. I would recommend you raise a case and in the meantime regrettably have to concede to whitelisting it in your code.

Comment: is there a site that lists all these beta/pilot fields on SObjects?

Comment: No sadly not, i agree it would be useful. Its worth pointing out that i am not saying this is the norm, i just think for whatever reason these 'leaks' occur now and again in my experience, its not the norm though.